# Confidence interval for statsmodels OLS model prediction

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I have a very similar problem to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559408/confidence-and-prediction-intervals-with-statsmodels?rq=1) question and it works for the training data. Now I´m trying to get the confidence interval for the predicted data:

```
from statsmodels.sandbox.regression.predstd import wls_prediction_std
#define y, X, X_forecast as pandas dataframes
regressor = sm.api.OLS(y, X).fit()
wls_prediction_std(regressor.predict(X_forecast))
```

But, of course, gives an error complaining about `regressor.predict` being an array. How can I calculate the confidence interval for the predicted regression values?

Comment: In my understanding, the confidence interval belongs to the curve you've obtained via regression. Thus, it does not really make sense to calculate it again for the test data (you call it "predicted"). You just do it for the training data as in the link you provide, and then you know that for any of your predictions you get the value at the curve +/- the confidence interval. Hope it helps.

Comment: I found a way: you just have to pass the argument exog to the wls_predictoin_std function call.

Answer (score 1):

you may have put the wrong parameter.

Let's try this one :

```
wls_prediction_std(regressor, exog=X_forecast, weights=None, alpha=0.05)
```