# Python confidence bands for predicted values

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am fitting a linear regression and want to have confidence bands projected for points that fall out of the range of the values fit.

From [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559408/confidence-and-prediction-intervals-with-statsmodels), there's an example of getting the bands for the values within the fit range:

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.sandbox.regression.predstd import wls_prediction_std

#Generate some data
n = 20
x = np.sort(np.random.normal(size=n))
e = np.random.normal(size=n)
y = 1 + 0.5*x + 1*e
X = sm.add_constant(x)

#Fit the model
re = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()


from statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence import summary_table

st, data, ss2 = summary_table(re, alpha=0.05)

#Get the confidence intervals
fittedvalues = data[:,2]
predict_mean_se  = data[:,3]
predict_mean_ci_low, predict_mean_ci_upp = data[:,4:6].T
predict_ci_low, predict_ci_upp = data[:,6:8].T

#Plot confidence intervals and data points
plt.plot(x, y, 'o')
plt.plot(x, fittedvalues, '-', lw=2)
plt.plot(x, predict_ci_low, 'r--', lw=2)
plt.plot(x, predict_ci_upp, 'r--', lw=2)
plt.plot(x, predict_mean_ci_low, 'r--', lw=2)
plt.plot(x, predict_mean_ci_upp, 'r--', lw=2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

However, this doesn't allow me to extend the bands to predicted values. How would I go about extending these bounds to values outside of the range of the fit values, e.g. for `x=5`?