# Subset data points outside confidence interval

Tags: python-3.x, statsmodels

Using the same example as from this previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559408/confidence-and-prediction-intervals-with-statsmodels/17560456#17560456) (code pasted below), we can get the 95% CI with the `summary_table` function from [statsmodels outliers_influence](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/_modules/statsmodels/stats/outliers_influence.html). But now, how would it be possible to only subset the data points (`x` and `y`) that are outside the confidence interval?

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence import summary_table

#measurements genre
n = 100
x = np.linspace(0, 10, n)
e = np.random.normal(size=n)
y = 1 + 0.5*x + 2*e
X = sm.add_constant(x)
re = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()
st, data, ss2 = summary_table(re, alpha=0.05)
predict_ci_low, predict_ci_upp = data[:, 6:8].T
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be a bit late for this, but you could put it in a `pandas.DataFrame` and filter depending on a list of booleans. Assuming I got your question:

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence import summary_table
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

## Import pandas
import pandas as pd

#measurements genre
n = 100
x = np.linspace(0, 10, n)
e = np.random.normal(size=n)
y = 1 + 0.5*x + 2*e
X = sm.add_constant(x)
re = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()
st, data, ss2 = summary_table(re, alpha=0.05)

# Make prediction
prediction = re.predict(X)
predict_ci_low, predict_ci_upp = data[:, 6:8].T

# Put y and x in a pd.DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(y).set_index(x)

# Get the y values that are out of the ci intervals. This could be done directly in the df indexer
out_up = y > predict_ci_upp
out_down = y < predict_ci_low

# Plot everything
plot.plot(x, y, label = 'train')
plot.plot(df[out_up], marker = 'o', linewidth = 0)
plot.plot(df[out_down], marker = 'o', linewidth = 0)
plot.plot(x, predictionTrain, label = 'prediction')
plot.plot(x, predict_ci_upp, label = 'ci_up')
plot.plot(x, predict_ci_low, label = 'ci_low')
plot.legend(loc='best')
```

Here is the resulting plot:

[image]