# python statsmodels linear regression

Tags: python, statistics, linear-regression, statsmodels

I am attempting to make a linear regression model based on pre project data and ultimately attempt to calculate some modeled data where I could compare pre/post project data... Can anyone tell me what the best proactice is else I maybe off in the weeds somewhere...

For starters:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ng = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/ngDataBaseline.csv',  thousands=',', index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)
ng.head()
```

This will output:

```
    HDD Therm
Date        
2011-10-01  386 498
2011-11-01  663 1810
2011-12-01  972 4263
2012-01-01  1131    5981
2012-02-01  977 6951
```

And from statsmodels to fit my model I am using:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

formula = 'Therm ~ HDD'
model = smf.ols(formula, data=ng)
results = model.fit()
results.summary()
```

[image]

```
inter = results.params['Intercept']
slope = results.params['HDD']
inter, slope
```

prints:

```
(-532.6244255918659, 6.331883644532255)
```

So now I think I can import post project data and use some simple math in this format to calculate modeled data:
`Y = mX + b`

```
ng_postproject = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/ng_postproject.csv',  thousands=',', index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)

ng_postproject.head()
```

And this will output:

```
    HDD Therm
Date        
2014-10-01  291 663
2014-11-01  545 1413
2014-12-01  1069    6754
2015-01-01  1134    7782
2015-02-01  1415    10285
```

This is what I am using to calculate a modeled Therm usage.

```
ng_postproject['Therm_modeled'] = ng_postproject['HDD'].apply(lambda x: x * slope + inter)


ng_postproject['Therm_modeled']

Date
2014-10-01    1309.953715
2014-11-01    2918.252161
2014-12-01    6236.159190
2015-01-01    6647.731627
2015-02-01    8426.990931
```

Now if I am not too far off in  the weeds I should be able to add in a column header and compare post/pre project data... It would be really nice too if I could implement a confidence interval as well... Thanks for any response.

Comment: Is there a reason why you went with the formula approach vs fitting X to y? I suppose the formula also fits with an intercept. I might suggest using both ways and seeing what the adjusted R-squared value is.

Comment: If you can try "days since begin date", you can convert the dates to numeric data. This might be worth a test, sometimes it is a useful technique.