# How to obtain prediction intervals with statsmodels timeseries models?

Tags: statsmodels

Is there a statsmodels API to retrieve prediction intervals from statsmodels timeseries models?

Currently, I'm manually calculating the prediction intervals using:

[image]

Here's my code.  First, get some sample data ...

```py
! python -c 'import datapackage' || pip install datapackage

%matplotlib inline

import datapackage

from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_acf
from statsmodels.tsa.api import SimpleExpSmoothing
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def get_data():
    # data licensed for non-commercial use only - https://datahub.io/core/bond-yields-uk-10y
    data_url = 'https://datahub.io/core/bond-yields-uk-10y/datapackage.json'

    resources = datapackage.Package(data_url).resources

    quarterly_csv_url = [pkg for pkg in resources if pkg.name == 'quarterly_csv'][0].descriptor['path']
    data = pd.read_csv(quarterly_csv_url)
    data = data.set_index('Date', drop=True).asfreq('Q')
    return data
```

Next, create a forecast and calculate the intervals:

```py
data = get_data()
data = data[ data.index > '2005/']

fit = SimpleExpSmoothing(data).fit()
fcast = fit.forecast(1).rename('Forecast')
xhat = fcast.get_values()[0]

z = 1.96
sse = fit.sse
predint_xminus = xhat - z * np.sqrt(sse/len(data))
predint_xplus  = xhat + z * np.sqrt(sse/len(data))
```

Plot the intervals ...

```py
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (20,5)

ax = data.plot(legend=True, title='British Goverment Bonds - 10y')
ax.set_xlabel('yield')

#
# 1-Step Prediction
#
prediction = pd.DataFrame( 
    data  = [ data.values[-1][0],  xhat ], 
    index = [ data.index[-1],      data.index[-1] + 1 ],
    columns = ['1-Step Predicted Rate']
)
_ = prediction.plot(ax=ax, color='black')

#
# upper 95% prediction interval
#
upper_pi_data = pd.DataFrame( 
    data  = [ xhat,           predint_xplus ], 
    index = [ data.index[-1], data.index[-1] + 1 ]
)
_ = upper_pi_data.plot(ax=ax, color='green', legend=False) 

#
# lower 95% prediction interval
#
lower_pi_data = pd.DataFrame( 
    data  = [ xhat,           predint_xminus ], 
    index = [ data.index[-1], data.index[-1] + 1 ]
)
_ = lower_pi_data.plot(ax=ax, color='green', legend=False)
```

[image]

I've found similar questions, but not for timeseries models:

- [confidence and prediction intervals with StatsModels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559408/confidence-and-prediction-intervals-with-statsmodels)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you check the assumption that the residuals are uncorrelated and you don't go farther than one step ahead I think your prediction interval is valid. Note: I would use the standard deviation of the residuals. See section 3.5 in [Forecasting Principles and Practice](https://otexts.com/fpp2/ets.html).

I'm pretty sure we need to place the model we are using into state space form according to Forecasting Principles and Practice for multi-step prediction intervals. See chapter 7.5 on exponential smoothing. The [State Space Modeling for Local Linear Trend](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/statespace_local_linear_trend.html) in statsmodels provides a working example. <s>It doesn't look like there is anything out of the box to produce these intervals in statsmodels.</s> I personally decided to use R to get my prediction intervals since the forecasting package provides these without a lot of additional effort.

Update: see comment below. Statsmodels now has state space representation for some exponential smoothing models.

Comment: In the [latest release](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/release/version0.11.html#statespace-models), statsmodels supports the [state space representation for exponential smoothing](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.exponential_smoothing.ExponentialSmoothing.html#statsmodels.tsa.statespace.exponential_smoothing.ExponentialSmoothing). There are some limits called out in the notes, but you can now get confidence intervals for an additive exponential smoothing model.